# How to make it possible to write xml files by matlab in pipeline tests from GitLab

Tags: matlab, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I am tring to run pipeline tests in GitLab for my code. It is testing whether the xml files are in correct format. There is another function "export_xml()" inside which are used to write the xml files in the temp path.

part of the code is like this:

```
...
fid=fopen(tempdir,filename),'w');
...
```

However, the test failed and the error says: Invalid file identifier. Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.

Does anyone know the solution of this problem? Thanks!